# Separate domain name for Wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I need to set-up 5 websites that have different domains as:

```
naomisport.com
naomikomestic.com
...
```

each of them does have sub-pages & news & ... .

In term of design & functionality, they can share the same plugins, theme and users, but I can not get my head around the choice of Wordpress Multisite & single Wordpress installation.

1. For single Wordpress, Can I have different domains per some specific page?
2. For Wordpress Multisite, can I have different domains name per website or does it have to be a sub-domain?
3. If I would go with Multisite, can I have the same Post management between all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question1: Yes, it possible.

Question2: Yes, you can have multi domina or multi subdomain.

Add Several WordPress Multisite Blogs With Different Domains
This section assumes that:

- You have a working WordPress Multisite installation
- Your server has a static IP address
- You are able to log in to your server console using a tool like PuTTY (Windows) or SSH (Linux and Mac OS X)
- You own at least one custom domain name for which you can configure DNS settings
- You have defined your primary domain and blog as described in the previous section and you are able to log in to the WordPress Multisite dashboard.

The WordPress MU Domain Mapping plugin allows users of a WordPress Multisite installation to map their blogs or websites to other domains or subdomains (Scenarios 2 and 3). This plugin is already installed in your Bitnami WordPress Multisite stack since v3.5.1-1. If you’re using an older version, you must manually install the plugin using the [plugin installation guide](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/#installation).

Question3: In wordpress multisite you have same panel but for every subdomain or domain you have separated management but you can have one username and password for management all panels.

For more information:

- https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress-multisite/configuration/configure-wordpress-multisite/
- https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/